# How to set checkout process per item basis

Tags: commerce

I am developing a site with Drupal Commerce.

The client needs a multiple recipient feature. He needs per-item per-recipient feature.

Suppose 1 customer buys 3 items, he will have 3 checkout box containing 1 item with all information to fill (like shipping info, gift message etc) in the checkout process and then goes to next line item using the same process, then goes to next.

Comment: @Clive Thanks for editing my post. In future I must care about those staff which are deleted.

Comment: I guess I have asked the toughest question for help.